# Increase an Object key in a JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
let $object= [
        {
            tagName: "01",
            contentID: [100, 200],
            occurrences: 2
        },
        {
            tagName: "02",
            contentID: [200, 300],
            occurrences: 2
        },
        {
            tagName: "03",
            contentID: [100, 200, 300],
            occurrences: 3
        },
        {
            tagName: "04",
            contentID: [300],
            occurrences: 1
        }];
```

I want to increase the value of `occurrences` when a `tagName` is matched. How should I increase the `occurrences` value/count?

// `let tagManagerArr = [];` //global scope

```
for (let content of contents) {
        contentId = content.contentID;
        entityType = content.entityType;
        let tags = content.tags,
            check = false;//check gives me whether a tagName is already present in the '$object' array..
     for (let tagName of tags) {
                console.log("---------------------------------------")
                 tagManagerArr.forEach(
                     (arrayItem) => {
                         if (arrayItem.tagName === tag) {
                            check = true;
                        }
                     }
                 );

                //tagManagerArr.find(
                 //   (element) => {
                  //      if (element.tagName === tagName) {
                 //           check = true;
                  //      }
                  //  });
                if (!check) {
                    tagObject = {};
                    tagObject['tagName'] = tagName;
                    tagObject['contentID'] = [];
                    tagObject['occurrences'] = 1;

                    tagObject['contentID'].push(contentId);
                } else {
                    tagManagerArr.find(
                        (element) => {
                            if (element.tagName === tagName) {
                                if (!element.contentID.includes(contentId)) {
                                    element.contentID.push(contentId);
                                }
                                element.occurrences += 1;
                            }
                        });
                }

                tagManagerArr.push(tagObject);
            }
}
```

this is working fine but with incorrect occurrences.. Any clue ?

Comment: This is not how [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) should be used

Comment: please rename `arr` to the name of later use.

Comment: Code would be so much better as an object and not an array of objects.

Comment: I changed .find() to forEach.. +1 for helping me follow best praoctices

Comment: @GopiGorantala Does the poorly named `$object` have to be an array. Code would be so more efficient if it were an object.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @epascarello, I actually named it as tagObject in my project, but renamed here.

Comment: @brk, I would like to increase the count of occurrences if the same tagName exists.. In my code above, occurrences is increased improperly.. so there is a bug.. I want to fix it..

Comment: My comment is it is not an object, it is an array. It would be better as a map or object where you look up things by a key and not have to loop an array every time you want to find if an item exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a map from tag names to properties will be much easier and more efficient:

```
// pick a better name
const map = new Map();

for (const content of contents) {
    for (const tagName of content.tags) {
        let tagObject = map.get(tagName);

        if (tagObject === undefined) {
            map.set(tagName, tagObject = {
                contentID: new Set(),
                occurrences: 0,
            });
        }

        tagObject.occurrences++;
        tagObject.contentID.add(content.contentID);
    }
}
```

Then you can convert it to the array format:

```
const tagManagerArr = Array.from(map,
    ([tagName, {contentID, occurrences}]) => ({
        tagName,
        contentID: Array.from(contentID),
        occurrences,
    }));
```

Comment: @GopiGorantala: Updated. Make sure you’re working in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), by the way. It’ll catch a lot of mistakes, like `entityType` being undeclared (if it is declared, it’s probably unnecessarily early – you can declare it right when you set it, as a `const`).

Answer (score 1):

Use an object instead.
The data format is up to you - make it so that its easy to use.

```
let tags = {
    "01": {
       contentID: [10, 20],
       occurrences: 0
    },
    "02": {
       contentID: [10, 20],
       occurrences: 0
    }
}
// get all tag names
const tagNames = Object.keys(tags);
// increment tag value
tags["01"].occurrences++;

Update: you can sort the array as well.
Object.keys(tags).map(tagName => tags[tagName]).sort((tag1, tag2) => {
    if (tag1.occurrences > tag2.occurrences) {return -1}
    if (tag1.occurrences < tag2.occurrences) {return 1}
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to sort the arrays of Objects.. so with my approach only it works as I want to do something as  $object.sort((a, b) => Number(a.occurrences) - Number(b.occurrences));

Comment: you can still get the sorted array after the data processing is done